# AWS Beanstalk Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, babeljs

```
var _config = require('./config/config.js');

var _config2 = _interopRequireDefault(_config);
```

Cannot find module **'./config/config.js'**

But this file exists. **Works fine on localhost, but throws this error AWS EBS.**

Comment: Were you ever able to find your solution to this Ankit?

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same problem, I had to add the files required for my application to run in the **buildspec.yml**

When it was failing my **buildspec.yml** file had just the code bellow on the artifacts section:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - app.js
    - package.json
```

I fixed it adding config/*

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - app.js
    - package.json
    - config/*
```

If you're having problems with some packages you can also add:

```
- node_modules/**/*
```